# CSS skew angle align with 3 rows

Tags: html, css

See attached image below. I want to preserve it with pure CSS. That means I'm only looking for a  CSS only solution.

[image]

Using this CSS code I can get middle row (look at the image) as I needed. But not for top and bottom rows. Problem is skew angle is not align like image.

```css
.slider-single {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.slider-single::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #0072c6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: skewX(-16deg) translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.skew-bar-top {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.skew-bar-top::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #21255d;
  transform: skewX(-16deg) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-single with-bg img">
    <div class="skew-bar-top"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          -- contents
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          -- contents
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skew-bar-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 3 rows, you can keep only one and play with backgrounds

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  border: solid #0000;
  border-width: 50px 0; /* control the width of the top/bottom border */
  background:
    /* the middle gradient */
    linear-gradient(110deg, blue 50%,red 50.1%) padding-box,
    /* the border gradient*/
    linear-gradient(110deg,red 50%,yellow 50.1%) border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box,border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Also like below for different coloration on each border:

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  border-top: 50px solid #0000;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background: 
    /* the middle gradient */
    linear-gradient(110deg,purple 50%,green 50.1%),
    /* the top gradient */
    linear-gradient(110deg,blue 50%,red 50.1%),
    /* the bottom gradient*/
    linear-gradient(110deg,red 50%,yellow 50.1%);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box,padding-box,border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much... This is what I needed. Sir, one thing can change the colors of bottom border?

Comment: Hello Sir, I just found there is a browser issue. On ms edge we can not see the top border.. Can you kindly tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made this code with looking though [This](http://www.cssaaa.com/css3/85.html) website.
Now, it enables you to scale the size. However, I can not just let the middle part be bigger because it is hard to calculate the position of the angle.
Here is the code:

```html
<title>测试</title>
<style type="text/css">
.RightAngleTrapezoid {
 width:120px;height:0;margin:100px auto;
 border-right:15px solid transparent;
 border-top:15px solid;
  position:absolute;
}
</style>
<button onclick="ChangeSize()">
  Test To change size
</button>
<input id="time" value="3">
<div id="Flag" style="transform:scale(0.5,1.1)">
<div id="UpPosition">
  <div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:red;transform:rotate(360deg);left:0;top:0;width:250"></div>
<div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:yellow;transform:rotate(180deg);left:250;top:0;width:180;"></div>
</div>

<div id="MiddlePosition">
  <div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:blue;transform:rotate(360deg);left:0;top:15;width:170;border-right:80px solid transparent;border-top:90px solid"></div>
<div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:red;transform:rotate(180deg);left:170;top:15;width:195;border-right:80px solid transparent;border-top:90px solid"></div>
</div>

<div id="DownPosition">
  <div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:red;transform:rotate(360deg);left:0;top:105;width:155"></div>
<div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:yellow;transform:rotate(180deg);left:155;top:105;width:275;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function ChangeSize(){ 
var element = document.getElementById("Flag");
  var ho = 0.5;
  var ve = 1.1;
  var times = document.getElementById("time").value;
  console.log(element);
element.setAttribute("style", "transform:scale("+ho * times + ","+ve * times + ");");
}
</script>
```

**Tips: You can put the code into an IDE because I do not know why it won't work with StackOverflow's test and you can test [Here](https://c.runoob.com/front-end/61/) online.**
This is the screenshot of the result(As you want):[image: The screenshot]

Comment: Sorry this is not what I need

Comment: @ugsgknt could you please describe what's wrong so I can better help you

Comment: Look at the attached image in my question.. You will see what I need

Comment: @ugsgknt I have already looked at it and you can try to put this code into an IDE so this will be shown properly. I do not know why it can't be shown here. Also, I edited my answer to add a screenshot. Or you can test the code [Here](https://htmledit.squarefree.com/).

Comment: I am going to use this design as a background in a slider. So it requied to be respoinsive. And also height of the middle row is dynamic..

Comment: @ugsgknt I will try to change my code. However, please be detail what you want to make next time because we know nothing about your program, so we will think the only thing you want to achieve is this flag.

Comment: @ugsgknt I made it can be stretch or shrink, but I could not just let the middle part do that. Maybe this time it can work. If it still not work, I have no idea, so I will delete this answer after you told me that is not working.